# Conditional UPDATE if new_value <= value_from_different_row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery, conditional-statements

Is there an elegant solution to perform an UPDATE in MySQL if and only if the value to be assigned to column X in my row is greater or equal to the same column X's value in another (specific) row?

I'm using a table with 2 columns as a key => value store, and I have something like this:

```
key            | value
---------------------------
period_a_begin | 2014-01-01
period_a_end   | 2014-01-15
period_b_begin | 2014-01-20
period_b_end   | 2014-02-15
```

How can I make sure that the new value for period_a_end is greater or equal to the value of period_a_begin value and less or equal to the value of period_b_begin in the same SQL query that I use to update period_a_end?

I've tried using subqueries, but without success:

```
UPDATE configtable
SET configtable.value=:myvalue
WHERE configtable.key="period_a_end"
AND :myvalue >= (SELECT configtable.value FROM configtable WHERE configtable.key = "period_a_begin")
AND :myvalue <= (SELECT configtable.value FROM configtable WHERE configtable.key = "period_b_begin");
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
You can't specify target table configtable for update in FROM clause
```

While I understand why that error pops up, I fail to find a way to find a way to make this work without removing the whole check from my prepared statement. :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so elegant, but it should work.  You can use an additional level of nested queries:

```
UPDATE configtable
    SET configtable.value = :myvalue
WHERE configtable.key="period_a_end" AND
      :myvalue >= (select value from (SELECT ct.value FROM configtable ct WHERE ct.key = "period_a_begin") ct) AND
      :myvalue <= (select value from (SELECT ct.value FROM configtable ct WHERE ct.key = "period_b_begin") ct);
```

Comment: Thanks, but not only is this not elegant, I'm also not sure if this behavior of the MySQL server couldn't be considered a bug (und thus be fixed/changed some time in the future.

Comment: @user3485397 . . . I can appreciate the lack of elegance, but I don't know what you mean by the "bug" part.  The query with or without the additional layer of subqueries is standard SQL.  The second layer is needed to get around a bug in the current MySQL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've chosen to implement my check in PHP using multiple queries, packing the whole check into a single SQL transaction. But beware that transaction to not work with the MyISAM storage engine, so you'll have to use InnoDB or some other engine that supports transactions.

Besides being faster then stored procedures, this solution also seems more portable (at least on the database side) to me.